# Misplaced Whitespace in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the following code to modify the way the author-year style is shown in the bibliography:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
   \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \printnames{author}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \usebibmacro{journal}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \printfield{volume}%
   \setunit{\addspace}% Add a space
   \printfield{parens}{\printfield{year}}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{\addperiod\space}% Add a period and a space
   \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

An example of the output of this is:

```
Tversky, Amos and Daniel Kahneman, “Advances in prospect theory: Cumulative representation of uncertainty”, Journal of Risk and Uncertainty, 5( 1992), pp. 297–323.
```

The parathesis around the year is wrong the whitespace is inside of the paranthesis "5( 1992)" but it should be before the paranthesis "5 (1992)"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to reproduce the exact issue you were talking about in the question with the code as shown, but I suggest the following change.

```
\printfield{parens}{\printfield{year}}%
```

will not wrap the year in parentheses. It will attempt to print a field called `parens`, which does not exist, and will then print the year. You probably want something like

```
\printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}%
```

Usually though, you should not use `\printfield{year}` to print the year. The year should be printed as part of the date with `\printdate` (the output of `\printdate` can be modified with the `date` option or by modifying the relevant date formatting macros for the selected option).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
   \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \printnames{author}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \usebibmacro{journal}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \printfield{volume}%
   \setunit{\addspace}% Add a space
   \printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% Add a comma and a space
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{\addperiod\space}% Add a period and a space
   \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19 (1998), pp. 377–395.]

A radical redefinition of the drivers is not needed to change the output slightly. Often it is more efficient, convenient and safe to modify only the relevant bibmacros, field formats or delimiter commands.